# How to put a DevExpress extended component (RibbonPageGroup) on the toolbox for WinForms

Tags: winforms, components, controls, devexpress

I have extended a DevExpress **component** (not a control), a RibbonPageGroup, to be used around my application. I like to see it in the toolbox in the VS2010 designer but "it won't appear" here. I assume it has to do with the inheritance hierarchy of the extended component. It doesn't derive from control.

Am I going the wrong way by extending a Type that itself extends Component. Or can I make it possible to appear on the toolbox and drag and drop it on RibbonControls.

Any answer would be appreciated. Tia, Joep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from DevExpress:

---

```
[ToolboxItem(true), DesignTimeVisible(true)] public class MyRibbonPageGroup : RibbonPageGroup {...
```

However, I should mention that this is not a visual component, so when being placed onto a form, it will appear at the bottom of the screen with all other non-visual components.

---

It surprises me that it's not a visual component. When I add a pagegroup via the RibbonPage "accelerator" pop-menu a new pagegroup appears. My intention was to create a custom pagegroup with a print and printpreview button with a public LayoutControl (which would be available / settable in the designer). Because I use this combination of print(preview) on many forms I create I thought it would be a good idea to encapsulate this functionality into a custom "control"...which I could easily drop on RibbonPages everywhere....

And it's true that the component appears at the bottom of the page. I would like to "cling" it onto a certain pagegroup design-time.